# a numeric to string conversion in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, converters, numeric

I need a code which receive a 1xn number array like [2 , 6, 9] and converts it to a 1x1 string data in this way :

2, 6, 9

or this way :

2, 6, 9,

Answer (score 4):

```
s = sprintf('%d,', a)
```

where `a` is your vector.

Comment: actually i need it to be in a 1x1 dimension ,,,,,, is there any way i can do it

Answer (score 0):

For converting a vector of numbers to a string, you can use `num2str` function.
Documentation is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html.

I don't know if there's a way to store a string as an 1x1 element, and `sprintf` doesn't do it for sure, as it's output is a character array.

Comment: You can also use `s = num2str(a , '%d,')` and get the same results as I posted above - they are both character arrays.

Comment: Indeed, but none of this functions stores the output string as 1x1 string element.

Comment: @Mohamad Pishdad: After some further research on your issue, I really didn't found any way to store a string as an 1x1 element - "scalar" of any type. Can you tell us for which purpose you want to do this, so we maybe can suggest you an alternative?